# PowerShell Clickable URL creation

Tags: string, powershell

I'm having trouble to make my URL clickable in HTML. Even when using the escaping character, it's not accepted as valid output. Although, when I try this in the console it gives the desired result:

```
"<a href=`"$Target`">$Target</a>"
<a href="\\domain.net\share">\\domain.net\share</a>
```

Small piece of the code:

```
$Server = "UNC"
$Target = "\\domain.net\share"

$HTMLarrayAllPaths = "<li>$(if ($Server -ne "UNC") {"$Server, $Target"} else { "<a href=`"$Target`">$Target</a>" })</li>"

$HTMLarrayAllPaths
```

When trying with `Out-String` it also ends with an error. I can't seem to find my way around this. Thank you for your advice or help, always appreciated from the nice people here at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working out as to why but i had to add some quotes around $target between the backticks

```
$HTMLarrayAllPaths = "<li>$(if ($Server -ne "UNC") {"$Server, $Target"} else { "<a href=`""$Target"`">$Target</a>" })</li>"
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! Awesome! :) I couldn't figure it out myself, I'm glad you could help me. Next time I'll have to play a bit more with the double quotes.